# Find the Bell States of A and B in the following scenario

Tags: entanglement, bell-experiment, bell-basis

Let A has quantum memories $M_1$ and $M_2$ and B has quantum memories $M_3$ and $M_4$ capable of holding one qubit.

2 Bell states are shared among A & B in the following way:

First Bell state $|B_{00}\rangle$ has been shared among $M_1$ and $M_3$. 
Second Bell state $|B_{00}\rangle $ has been shared among $M_2$ and $M_4$.

Assume all calculations are in Bell basis.

How to calculate the Bell states of A[$M_1$ and $M_2$] and B[$M_3$ and $M_4$]?

Comment: Why people are downvoting the question? Whats wrong in the question?

Comment: Please start using proper [LaTeX formatting](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/tutorial-how-to-use-tex-mathjax-to-render-math-notation) in your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply start by writing out everything
$$
|B_{00}\rangle_{13}|B_{00}\rangle_{24}=\frac12\left(|00\rangle_{13}|00\rangle_{24}+|00\rangle|11\rangle+|11\rangle|00\rangle+|11\rangle|11\rangle\right)
$$
Let me rearrange each of these terms
$$
\frac12\left(|00\rangle_{12}|00\rangle_{34}+|01\rangle|01\rangle+|10\rangle|10\rangle+|11\rangle|11\rangle\right).
$$
Now you can use the fact that the Bell states form a basis to rewrite each of those terms, although maybe it helps to notice that
$$
|00\rangle_{12}|00\rangle_{34}+|11\rangle|11\rangle=|B_{00}\rangle|B_{00}\rangle+|B_{01}\rangle|B_{01}\rangle
$$
Hence, we get a final answer of
$$
\frac12\left(|B_{00}\rangle|B_{00}\rangle+|B_{01}\rangle|B_{01}\rangle+|B_{10}\rangle|B_{10}\rangle+|B_{11}\rangle|B_{11}\rangle\right)
$$